# IQueryable Expression Translation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-expressions

I am creating an IQueryable that I want to use for a query passed to entity framework.  My repository does not expose queryable.

```
 var query = new List<Entity>().AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Property == "argument");
```

I have a method on my repository that will take in an IQueryable.

How do I query my DbSet with the same queryable?  I am trying to extract the expression from the queryable to build a new expression for the dbset.  Here is what I have so far but it does not work:

```
public IDbSet<TEntity> DbSet { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(IQueryable<TEntity> queryable)
{
      var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TEntity));
      var body = queryable.Expression;

      var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, parameter);
      var result =  DbSet.Where(lambda);
      return null;
}
```

The code fails when I try and create the lambda with the following error:
Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyTEntity]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'

I'm clearly not building the expression correctly, what am I missing?  Is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Also I've seen some examples that show an Expression should have a parameters property.  But no matter what type of expression type I cast to, and this one is ConstantExpression, I don't see a parameters property from the IQueryable.Expression.

Comment: The simpler interface I would recommend would be `public List<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter) { return DbSet.Where(filter).ToList(); }`. (Perhaps adding in an `AsNoTracking()` as well.) This would allow using it as `Find(x => x.Property == "argument")`. I'm guessing you have a reason for your current design, though. Can you explain what you want to accomplish that isn't adequately handled by what I would have done?

Comment: That's a good idea and I might use that but here is why I've gone with my original design.  The repository is based on domain level entities. The objects I actually query for on the client side, go through a service layer which is based on the data contracts.  My service Find method takes in a Queryable<TDataContract> and I use automapper to project it to the domain level TEntity.  My desire is to have a query on the client that looks like: var query = new List<DataContract>().AsQueryable().Where(...) service.Find(query)   That is the explanation, good or bad design, I haven't decided yet.

Comment: I think any way I go here, I need to get the parameters from the queryable.  Since I'm projecting my domain models I don't see a clear path without IQueryable.  I just need a way to take in an iqueryable and build the lambda expression from its expression tree.

Comment: I honestly don't understand people's aversion of exposing `IQueryable<T>`. This is an AWFUL API you are making. Its complicated, buggy (as evidenced by you coming here), difficult to conceptualize, (since you can't figure out how to pass an `IQueryable<T>` into Find (hint, YOU CAN'T)). Quite frankly if you did have the `IQueryable<T>` why not use that...Not to mention its so completely non-standard.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, `queryable.Expression` represents the whole expression `Queryable.Where(constantList, x => x.Property == "argument")`. If you want just the `Where()` lambda, you need to extract it. To do that, you could use code like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find<TEntity>(IQueryable<TEntity> queryable)
{
    var methodCall = queryable.Expression as MethodCallExpression;
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, Expression<Func<TEntity,Boolean>>, IQueryable<TEntity>> whereDelegate = Queryable.Where;

    if (methodCall.Method == whereDelegate.Method
        && methodCall.Arguments[0] is ConstantExpression)
    {
        var whereLambdaQuote = (UnaryExpression)methodCall.Arguments[1];
        var whereLambda = (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)whereLambdaQuote.Operand;

        var result = DbSet.Where(whereLambda);
    }

    return null;
}
```