# Conditional generic Where equals clause in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm trying to create a where clause that I can pass in a func and a property then compare them. I have a long list of different properties I need to compare so I want an extension method to wrap it.

Here's how I want to use it:

```
string transactionNumber = "12345";
Queryable<TranCard> transactions = _context.TranCard
    .WhereEquals(t => t.TransactionNumber, transactionNumber)
    .ToList();
```

Here's the extension method I currently have that's causing me problems:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEquals<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Func<T, string> expression, string queryParam)
    {
        return source.Where(t => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryParam)
                                 || expression != null
                                 && string.Equals(queryParam.Trim(), expression.Invoke(t).Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

When I try to run this it's throwing the following runtime error message:
**"Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'"**

Comment: Is there a stack trace? The method works fine for me on a list of objects, so my next guess would be EF is having trouble SQLifying it.

Comment: This is not how expression works with IQueryable. You need to generate the Expression tree for IQueryable instead of invoking it. The expressions are evaluated by underlying provider. @EdPlunkett You got it working because that's in memory object and not object to sql(Underlying provider requires map for expression to generate respective sql statement). I can't explain it all in the comment but hope OP will get the gist.

Comment: @vendettamit do you have any tips on how to refactor the extension method in order to make this work ?

Comment: May be this [Similar Discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355993/iqueryable-expression-translation) will help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by separating out the calls. This also made it more easy to read!

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereEquals<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Func<T, string> expression, string queryParam)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryParam))
        {
            return source;
        }

        return source.Where(x => expression(x).Trim().ToLower() == queryParam.Trim().ToLower());
    }
```

Thanks to everyone for your help!